# Woocommerce create order after successful payment only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce for my e-commerce website. I know Woocommerce create the order before confirming the payment. Is it possible to create the order only if payment is successful?

Comment: I'm sure you can, but why would you want to do this? If an order fails, would it not be better to have a record of the order and then reach out to the customer? You would lose sales if you did this.

Comment: I need it for accounts purposes and the order id sequence must be continuous

Comment: There are better ways to do this, since you are essentially changing WordPress functionality - and will most likely cause issues in the future. On successful order, you could add data to a meta field instead. That way you can keep an unbroken sequence. You should also add the order sequence to your original question, since that is very important information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Woocommerce creates the order before the payment process. I think a possible solution is to check the order status on thank you page.
Woocommerce falls on thank you page after checkout and provides the hook *'woocommerce_thankyou'*. If payment was not completed the status can be *'failed'* or *'pending'*
This is some example code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'remove_order_on_failed_payment', 10, 1 );
function remove_order_on_failed_payment( $order_id ) {
    // Get an instance of the order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if( in_array( $order->get_status(), ['failed', 'pending'] ) ) {
        wp_delete_post($order_id,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the sequence must be continuous. For example, I delete an order having order id 5 then the next order will be 6 and the sequence 1,2,3,4,6. If there are any ways to reset the order id that can help me.